# Python - average of unique values

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
DATE,TEMP
0101,39.0
0102,40.9
0103,44.4
0104,41.0
0105,40.0
0106,42.2
...
0101,41.0
0102,39.9
0103,44.6
0104,42.0
0105,43.0
0106,42.4
```

It's a list of temperatures for specific dates. It contains data for several years so the same dates occur multiple times. I would like to average the temperature so that I get a new table where each date is only occurring once and has the average temperature for that date in the second column.

I know that Stack Overflow requires you to include what you've attempted, but I really don't know how to do this and couldn't find any other answers on this.

I hope someone can help. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using / familiar with any data-analysis libraries? (Such as `numpy` or `pandas`)? These would be perfect here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use pandas, and run the groupby command, when df is your data frame:

```
df.groupby('DATE').mean()
```

Here is some toy example to depict the behaviour

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,1,2,3],"b":[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
df.groupby('a').mean()
```

Will result in

```
a   b
1   2.5
2   3.5
3   4.5
```

When the original dataframe was

```
    a   b
0   1   1
1   2   2
2   3   3
3   1   4
4   2   5
5   3   6
```

Comment: Wow, that was so much easier than I expected. Thanks @Miriam .

Answer (score 2):

If you can use the defaultdict pacakge from collections, makes this type of thing pretty easy.

Assuming your list is in the same directory as the python script and it looks like this:

list.csv:

`DATE,TEMP
0101,39.0
0102,40.9
0103,44.4
0104,41.0
0105,40.0
0106,42.2
0101,39.0
0102,40.9
0103,44.4
0104,41.0
0105,40.0
0106,42.2`

Here is the code I used to print out the averages.

```
#test.py
#usage: python test.py list.csv
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

#Open a file who is listed in the command line in the second position
with open(sys.argv[1]) as File:

    #Skip the first line of the file, if its just "data,value"
    File.next()

    #Create a dictionary of lists
    ourDict = defaultdict(list)

    #parse the file, line by line
    for each in File:
        # Split the file, by a comma,
        #or whatever separates them (Comma Seperated Values = CSV)
        each = each.split(',')

        # now each[0] is a year, and each[1] is a value.
        # We use each[0] as the key, and append vallues to the list
        ourDict[each[0]].append(float(each[1]))

    print "Date\tValue"
    for key,value in ourDict.items():
        # Average is the sum of the value of all members of the list
        # divided by the list's length
        print key,'\t',sum(value)/len(value)
```